# Safari does not show pinned tab icon

Tags: svg, safari, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to add a pinned icon to my site.  I am using the following in my HEAD HTML:

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/icons/dfstar.svg" color="blue">
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  I verified that the icon is there.  i.e. I tried to open "/icons/favicon.svg" directly in the browser, and that worked.

I searched and found the following suggestions which I tried:

- Make sure SVG is 100% black and there is only one color.
- Viewbox set to 16 x 16
- Only one path in SVG.
- Delete contents of ~/Libary/Safari/Template Icons folder and restart Safari
- Clear browser cache

But none of them worked.  I'm still just getting an icon with the first letter of my domain name. I am testing in Safari 10.0 on OSX 11.

The interesting thing is that I tried with some well-known sites such as Wikipedia, Google, Yahoo, and CNN.  All of them showed a pinned tab icon.  But when I looked at those sites' source with Web Inspector, I didn't see a mask-icon link tag for any of them.  So maybe Safari uses some other method to get a site's pinned icon?

Comment: I'm running into this same issue!! Has anyone here been able to successfully implement this?